# Email inbox not opening with react native email link

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Hello my name is Rajdeep Singh. I was trying to open the gmail inbox in react native with react-native-email-link.The following code is the code which is not working.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { openInbox } from 'react-native-email-link';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.buttonstyle}
        onPress={() => {
          openInbox();
        }}>
        <Text>OPEN MAIL APP</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonstyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    marginTop: 150,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

So what is happening is that when I am clicking on the open mail app button nothing is happening.

Please help me.

Comment: did you add `"plugins": ["react-native-email-link"]` to config file?

Comment: Did you follow post installations steps? https://github.com/flexible-agency/react-native-email-link#2-post-install-steps

Answer (score 0):

Note! **You can test only on real devices**. Do not forget for post install steps for [iOS](https://github.com/includable/react-native-email-link#2-post-install-steps). This is my implementation, which works on iOS and on Android.

```
import * as RNEmailLink from 'react-native-email-link';

 const handlePressGoToInbox = useCallback(() => {
    try {
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        require('react-native-email-link/src/ios')
          .askAppChoice()
          .then((selectedApp: string) => {
            if (selectedApp) {
              RNEmailLink.openInbox({
                app: selectedApp,
              }).catch((error) => error));
            }
          });
      } else {
        RNEmailLink.openInbox().catch((error) => error));
      }
    } catch (error) {
     console.log(error)
    }
  }, [dispatch]);
```